# Hiding nsfw commands from help list

Tags: javascript

havent seen any answers for this yet.

Im looking for a way to Hide any nsfw commands i have for my discord.js bot.
I want it to show only when the channel the help command is done in is marked nsfw.

so if the channel is marked nsfw, it shows the nsfw category and commands. if it is not marked nsfw it hides the nsfw category and commands.

thank you for any help i can get.

*this shows every command and their respective category*

this is my help command code -

```
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");

module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    category: "info",
    description: "Tells you the commads currently able to be used",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if(args[0]){
            return getCMD(client, message, args[0]);
        }else{
            return getALL(client, message);
        }
    }
}

function getALL(client, message){
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)

    const commands = (category) => {
        return client.commands
            .filter(cmd => cmd.category === category)
            .map(cmd => `**|-** \`${cmd.name}\``)
            .join("\n");
    }

    const info = client.categories
        .map(cat => stripIndents`**${cat[0].toUpperCase() + cat.slice(1)}** \n${commands(cat)}`)
        .reduce((string, category) => string + "\n" + category);

    return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(info));
}

function getCMD(client, message, input){
    const embed = new RichEmbed()

    const cmd = client.commands.get(input.toLowerCase()) || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(input.toLowerCase()));

    let info = `No Information found for command **${input.toLowerCase()}**`;

    if(!cmd){
        return message.channel.send(embed.setColor("#ff0000").setDescription(info));
    }

    if(cmd.name) info = `**Command Name -** ${cmd.name}`;
    if(cmd.aliases) info += `\n**Aliases -** ${cmd.aliases.map(a => `\`${a}\``).join(", ")}`;
    if(cmd.description) info += `**\nDescription -** ${cmd.description}`;
    if(cmd.category) info += `**\nCategory -** ${cmd.category}`;
    if(cmd.usage) {
        info += `**\nUsage -** ${cmd.usage}`
        embed.setFooter(`Syntax <> = Required, [] = Optional`);
    }

    embed.setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL);

    return message.channel.send(embed.setColor("GREEN").setDescription(info));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way create exclude arr, and push 'nsfw' here if command channel nsfw flag = false, then check it on filter.

```js
 const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");

module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    category: "info",
    description: "Tells you the commads currently able to be used",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if(args[0]){
            return getCMD(client, message, args[0]);
        }else{
            return getALL(client, message);
        }
    }
}

function getALL(client, message){
    let excludeCategoryArr = [];
    if(!message.channel.nsfw) excludeCategoryArr.push('nsfw')
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)

    const commands = (category) => {
        return client.commands
            .filter(cmd => cmd.category === category && !excludeCategoryArr.includes(cmd.category))
            .map(cmd => `**|-** \`${cmd.name}\``)
            .join("\n");
    }

    const info = client.categories
        .filter(category => !excludeCategoryArr.includes(category))
        .map(cat => stripIndents`**${cat[0].toUpperCase() + cat.slice(1)}** \n${commands(cat)}`)
        .reduce((string, category) => string + "\n" + category);

    return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(info));
}

function getCMD(client, message, input){

    const embed = new RichEmbed()

    const cmd = client.commands.get(input.toLowerCase()) || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(input.toLowerCase()));

    let info = `No Information found for command **${input.toLowerCase()}**`;

    if(!cmd){
        return message.channel.send(embed.setColor("#ff0000").setDescription(info));
    }

    if(cmd.category === 'nsfw' && !message.channel.nsfw) {
        return message.reply('I can`t show NSWF command in not nsfw channel')
    }

    if(cmd.name) info = `**Command Name -** ${cmd.name}`;
    if(cmd.aliases) info += `\n**Aliases -** ${cmd.aliases.map(a => `\`${a}\``).join(", ")}`;
    if(cmd.description) info += `**\nDescription -** ${cmd.description}`;
    if(cmd.category) info += `**\nCategory -** ${cmd.category}`;
    if(cmd.usage) {
        info += `**\nUsage -** ${cmd.usage}`
        embed.setFooter(`Syntax <> = Required, [] = Optional`);
    }

    embed.setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL);

    return message.channel.send(embed.setColor("GREEN").setDescription(info));
}
```

Comment: If its possible, i tried to figure out how to hide my commands for admins, so if a admin did the help command if would show moderation commands for them, i seem to not be able to figure it out.
this is what im using, or trying to use.
```if(cmd.category === 'moderation' && !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        return message.channel.send("You dont have the permissions to use these")
    }```